# TaQL selection by removing "rows"

Tags: taql

I have one abhorrend table, no index, no keys, no IDs, no order, 25 columns, 19 million rows.

I need to select all rows that do not fulfill 3 sets of conditions:

```
19<columnT<27 && columnD==14
31<columnT<43 && columnD==17
57<columnT<71 && columnD==62
```

(In fact there are hundreds of conditions alike). It is not a strict SQL language but a SQL-ish one named TaQL ("Table Query Language").
What I tried:

```
select * 
from hugetable 
where not exists( 
    select * 
    from hugetable TT 
   where ((TT.columnT>19 && TT.columnT<27 && TT.columnD==14) ||
         (TT.columnT>31 && TT.columnT<43 && TT.columnD==17) ||
         (TT.columnT>57 && TT.columnT<71 && TT.columnD==62) ))
```

The selected rows are 0, but I know there should be more than 12 million!
Please help :-(

Comment: "It is not a strict SQL language but a SQL-ish one"; So what language *are* you using?

Comment: If you are not using SQL, you shouldn't tag your question with `sql`

Comment: I suppose there's no `<sql-ish>` tag available.

Comment: Put those _hundreds of conditions_ values in a temporary table. (3 columns).

Comment: The language I am employing is TaQL ("Table Query language").

Comment: Stackoverflow demands to employ one pre-defined tag. "taql" does not exists, so i guessed sql could fit.

Comment: Any null-able columns?

Comment: @jarlh no null-able columns.

Comment: The subquery in your `NOT EXISTS` is not correlated to the main query. Something like `NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM hugetable TT2  WHERE (some conditions) && TT2.PrimaryKey == TT.PrimaryKey )`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an EXCEPT if TaQL supports it:-

```
select TT.* 
from hugetable TT

Except

Select TT.*
from hugetable TT
 where  (    (TT.columnT > 19 AND TT.columnT < 27 AND TT.columnD = 14)
          OR (TT.columnT > 31 AND TT.columnT < 43 AND TT.columnD = 17)
          OR (TT.columnT > 57 AND TT.columnT < 71 AND TT.columnD = 62));
```

If that isn't possible, could you add an additional flag column and then update it as per your criteria (e.g. default it to 1 then update to 0 based on your where clause)?

Comment: TaQL does not understand the dot in selection. I mean:
     TT.*
It says the dot is an error.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is ok with the syntax but i assume that the issue is with the exclusion list...

the exclusion will be working fine with a column being used for comparison

```
 select * 
    from hugetable 
    where columnT NOT IN
    (     select columnT
        from hugetable TT 
       where ((TT.columnT>19 && TT.columnT<27 && TT.columnD==14) ||
             (TT.columnT>31 && TT.columnT<43 && TT.columnD==17) ||
             (TT.columnT>57 && TT.columnT<71 && TT.columnD==62) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by HoneyBadger the query doesn't work as expected because the subquery is not correlated to the outside one.

As an alternative you could use this

```
select *
from hugetable
where
    (columnD == 14 && ( columnT <= 19 || columnT >= 27)) ||
    (columnD == 17 && ( columnT <= 31 || columnT >= 43)) ||
    (columnD == 62 && ( columnT <= 57 || columnT >= 71)) ||
    columnD not in (14, 17, 52)
```

Note that the not in at the end is important so you'd consider records where columnD = 5 for instance.
I used the same syntax you did but maybe your sql-ish language has the NOT BETWEEN available.

Comment: The conditions inside the WHERE are organized into 826 sets of similar ones. I just wrote a tiny little example of 3 of them.

Comment: @Hermenegildo I know you mentioned it in your question but I worked with what you supplied but from my sample you can see how to include more. In terms of solutions, with 826 I'd be looking into generating the query via a script or using excel formula you can generate each set as a line then copy paste the generated code into any text editor. Remember to put all the 826 values in the not in.

Answer (score 0):

I tested most of provided and deleted answers, and I was able to achieved what I wanted.
The dot in selection does not work in TaQL, it says there is an error in:
    select TT.*